# jquery - why do i need live() in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind, live, autosuggest

I have a somewhat odd situation. I understand the premise of the live() and bind() functions, yet in a situation where i believe i dont need them, i seemingly do. I will explain.

I made an autosuggest in jquery. I included autosuggest.js at the top of my page. I then have an input field.

The basis of the JS works around:

```
$(".autosuggest").keyup(function()
{
}
```

This works - on keyup, my function executes etc as expected - i dont need to use live() or bind() as the input field is on the page from the get go...

Now.. I have also made a 'star rater' esque script.
I have various

elements (which are styled), and on hover they are restyled...

```
 $('.rating li').mouseover(function() {
}
```

does NOT work, YET

```
 $('.rating li').live('mouseover',function() {
}
```

DOES.

Why do i need to use 'live' in this situation, when i dont in the case of the autosuggest?

Thanks

Comment: Do the elements matching $('.rating li') exist when $(document).ready is executed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can imagine that would cause this is a lack of a domready event.  This should work:

```
$(function () {
    $('.rating li').mouseover(function() {
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. I had forgotten to put $(document).ready(function() { into that particular js file. So.. just to check i 'get this' without that snippet of code, the JS is loaded BEFORE the page content, hence why i needed live() BUT If enclosed in $(document).ready(function() {} the javascript is loaded after the page by some complex stuff within jquery? Thx

Comment: Yeah, the javascript is parsed and executed as it is read from the DOM, before the DOM is ready.  Putting it inside the DOM ready event makes it fire after everything on the page is loaded.

Answer (score 1):

the `.ratings li` isn't parsed yet when you have `.mouseover()` not working.

You can wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() {...});` or use `.live()` (which creates the binding for any currently parsed at that point in the script and any elements added in the future).

Answer (score 0):

Did you put

```
$('.rating li').mouseover(function() {
}
```

in  $(document).ready(function() {....}  ?

Even if you include a .js file, if the elements in the page ('rating li') are not loaded, the bind will not be made.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of you code, it's difficult to say for sure.  But my guess would be that your script is running before the pageload completes.  try wrapping your bindings (and anything else that depends on particular dom elements to exist) with a call to `$(document).ready(...)`.

something like this:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.rating li').mouseover(function() {
       // whatever
    });

    $(".autosuggest").keyup(function() {
       // whatever else
    });
});
```

If that's not it, then post more of your code, and we'll dig in further.

good luck.